# Could this string splitter be refactored or improved?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code snippet does the following:

Given a string like:  `"key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3"`, it will perform a lookup for key1 and set the value to value1 using jQuery:

```
$("#key1").val("value1");
```

My goal was to not assume the string is in the right format, so it might not have a `;`, or it might not have a `=`.  So the code should guard itself from crashing.

How could this be improved using the correct javascript style/idioms:

```
var myString = "key1=value1&key2=value2;key3=value3";
var kvp = myString.split(";");
if (kvp && kvp.length) {
    for (var x = 0; x < kvp.length; x++) {
        var parts = kvp[x];
        if (parts && parts.length && parts.indexOf("=") >= 0) {
           var kv = parts.split("=");
           $("#" + kv[0]).val(kv[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you saying that you want to split a string into key/value pairs but you may encounter multiple delimiter types? How would you know whether a character is part of a key or value or if it was a delimiter?

Comment: What the author is saying is that if the input is not in the correct format, the parser should gracefully error out rather than just going off into the weeds and crashing.  We have all seen parsing that had assumptions resulting in a bad pointer causing the application to crash when incorrect data is presented to the parser.

Comment: Right; my point being, how do you differentiate between `value1&key2=value2` being a single value of `key1` and being a malformed string? Assumptions will have to be made somewhere, probably that `=` will not appear in a value, so if you see one, that means you've erroneously read in multiple values into one key

Comment: Might want to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would split it up in one function which parses the string, and one which does the DOM manipulation. Something like:

```
function parseString (str, sep, eq) {
  sep = sep || ';';
  eq = eq || '=';

  var result = {};

  if(!str)
    return result;

  var pairs = str.split(sep);
  for (var i = 0, len = pairs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split(eq);

    // Disregard if we don't have a key
    if(!pair[0].length)
      continue;

    result[pair[0]] = pair[1];
  }

  return result;
}

function setValues(params) {
  for(id in params)
    $('#' + id).value(params[id]);
}

// Add values for ids as specified in myString

var myString = "key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3";
setValues(parseString(myString));
```

**Update:**

If you know the code will run on a modern JS engine, you can use `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` for more succinct code. This will only work on ES5-compliant engines (i.e., not IE < 9).

```
function parseString (str, sep, eq) {
  sep = sep || ';';
  eq = eq || '=';

  if(!str)
    return {};

  function splitPair (pair) { return pair.split(eq) }

  function addResult (result, pair) {
    if(pair[0].length)
      result[pair[0]] = pair[1];

    return result;
  }

  return str.split(sep)
    .map(splitPair)
    .reduce(addResult, {});
}
```

Examples from using `parseString`:

```
console.log(parseString('key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3'));
{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }

console.log(parseString('=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3'));
{ key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }

console.log(parseString(';key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3'));
{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }

console.log(parseString('key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;'));
{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }

console.log(parseString('key1=value1'));
{ key1: 'value1' }

console.log(parseString('key1='));
{ key1: '' }

console.log(parseString('key1'));
{ key1: undefined }

console.log(parseString(''));
{}

console.log(parseString());
{}
```